# How to extract a tar gz file in chunk

Tags: linux, tar

I have a 10TB tar.gz and 16TB of total disk space;

I would like to extract the 10TB tar.gz file - such as it removescontent of the tar.gz chunk by chunk;

Is it possible? Or I must have 20TB+ disk space?

Comment: You want to consume the .tar.gz as it is read and its uncompress data written to the same storage. It's seems off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you may try `--checkpoint-action=ACTION` flag during extraction and provide `pkill -9` tar as part of its `exec` command. You can review this article for explanation on the said option:
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utar.htm

```
--checkpoint[=NUMBER]   Use "checkpoints": display a progress message every NUMBER records (default 10).
--checkpoint-action=ACTION  Execute ACTION at every checkpoint. ACTION may be one of the following:
exec=command    Execute the given command.
```

But of course its better that you go for sufficient disk space.